# Primefaces DataTable Selection's Attribute is Null if not rendered in Dialog

Tags: primefaces

I'm not sure if this is a limitation or a coding error on my part. I have a Primefaces DataTable that allows the user to select it (single select radio) and then click on a CommandButton to edit the data in a Dialog.

In the HTML code where I display the selected object, I omitted the ID, Lat, and Long attributes because a human user shouldn't be touching these attributes. The Dialog is showing the selected attributes correctly, however, when I tried to find the existing record using the selected object's ID for update, it thrown a no result error. When I checked the selected object's ID attribute, it has a value of NULL.

I tinker around with the HTML code and found that in order to have the any of the attributes copied to the selected object, the attributes must be shown in the XHTML. When I include the attribute as  with Render = False, the attribute will have a value of NULL. Any suggestions on hiding attributes that human users shouldn't modify beside using Disable tag attribute?

```
Class Property{
    Int ID;
    String Address;
    Long Lat;
    Long Long;
    String Desc;
}

public void modifyCurrentProject() {
    HashMap<String, Object> params = new HashMap();
    params.put("id", currentProject.getId());

    //fails to find Project by ID as currentProject.getID == null
    Project temp = (Project) dbu.findByNamedQuery("project.findID", params);

    //Omit statements to overwrite attached object's values before writing back to database 
    dbu.modifyEntity(); //dbu is another object to control database access
    currentProject = null;
}

<h:body>
    <p:growl id="projectMsg" showDetail="true"/>
    <h:form id="form">

        <p:dataTable id="projectTable" var="project" value="#{projectBacking.builder.projects}" selection="#{projectBacking.currentProject}" rowKey="#{project.id}">
            <f:facet name="header">My Project List
                <p:commandButton value="Add" type="button" onclick="PF('projectAdd').show()"/>
                <p:commandButton value="Edit" update=":editForm" oncomplete="PF('projectEdit').show()"/>
            </f:facet>

            <p:column selectionMode="single"/>   
            <p:column headerText="ID">
                <h:outputText value="#{project.id}"/>

            <p:column headerText="Description">
                <h:outputText value="#{project.property.description}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Street">
                <h:outputText value="#{project.street}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="City">
                <h:outputText value="#{project.city}"/>
            </p:column>
            <p:column headerText="Province">
                <h:outputText value="#{project.state}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Latitude">
                <h:outputText value="#{project.latitude}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Longitude">
                <h:outputText value="#{project.longitude}"/>
            </p:column>

            <p:column headerText="Status">
                <h:outputText value="#{project.status}"/>
            </p:column>

        </p:dataTable>
    </h:form>

<!-- Omitted the Add Project Dialog box -->

    <p:dialog header="Edit Project" modal="true" height="400" width="80%" widgetVar="projectEdit">
        <h:form id="editForm">
            <p:panel id="editProject" header="Edit Project" toggleable="true" closable="false">
                <!--<h:inputText id="id" value="#{projectBacking.currentProject.id}"/>-->

                <h:inputText id="country" value="#{projectBacking.currentProject.country}"/>

                <h:inputText id="lat" rendered="true" value="#{projectBacking.currentProject.latitude}"/>

                <h:inputText id="long" rendered="true" value="#{projectBacking.currentProject.longitude}"/>

                <h:outputLabel for="desc" value="Description" />
                <h:inputText id="desc" value="#{projectBacking.currentProject.description}"/>

                <h:outputLabel for="street" value="Street" />
                <h:inputText id="street" value="#{projectBacking.currentProject.street}"/>
                <h:message for="street"/>

                <h:outputLabel for="city" value="City:" />
                <h:inputText id="city" required="false" value="#{projectBacking.currentProject.city}"/>
                <h:message for="city" />

                <h:outputLabel for="state" value="Province" />
                <h:inputText id="state" required="true" value="#{projectBacking.currentProject.state}"/>             

                <h:commandButton value="Save Project" type="submit" action="#{projectBacking.modifyCurrentProject()}">
                </h:commandButton>

            </p:panel>
        </h:form>
    </p:dialog>                  
</h:body>
```

Comment: please add your dialog and your managed (the way you get the data) i am sure it will help to understand the problem

Answer (score 0):

After placing some more breakpoints in the code, I discovered that upon saving the changes in the Dialog, it's creating a new backing bean. If the  is set to Render=false, Disabled=true, or ReadOnly=true then new backing bean's object's value will not be set and retain the initial value as specified in the object's constructor.

Basically, the cause is incorrect scope. I was using Request scope when the problem occurred. However, changing to Session scope resolved it.